# Multiple getJSON requests inside array

Tags: jquery

I have the following JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var names = ['item1', 'item2'];
    var series1 = [{ name: '', data: []}];
    var series2 = [{ name: '', data: []}];
    var seriesCounter = 0;
    ....
    renderCharts(url, otherUrl);

    function renderCharts(url, otherUrl) {
        if (otherUrl != '') {
            $.each(names, function (i, name) {

                $.getJSON('somurl', function (items) {
                    series1[i].name = name;

                    $.each(items.somedata, function (j, item) {
                        series1[i].data.push({
                            x: Date.parse(item.key),
                            y: item.value
                        })
                    });

                    seriesCounter++;

                    if (seriesCounter == names.length) {
                        ... render chart once all data has been downloaded
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        $.getJSON(url, function (items) {
            $.each(items.otherData, function (i, item) {
                series2[0].data.push({
                    x: Date.parse(item.Key),
                    y: item.Value
                })
            });

            // render other chart
        });
    }
}
```

I can't get this to work. Every time I run this I never enter the following condition:

```
if (seriesCounter == names.length) {
    ... render chart once all data has been downloaded
}
```

If I only have one item in the names array, it works just fine. The moment I add two, the condition never becomes true and therefore my charts never renders.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tested it in a browser with a console such as firefox with firebug or google chrome to see if the ajax (json) request is completing successfully?

Comment: Yes, all requests complete successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `series1` variable is defined as an array with exactly one element (an object) in it, but within the `$.each(names, function (i, name) {` loop you are treating it as if it had more elements and trying to access `series1[i]` for values of `i` that are greater than 0. When `i` is 1 you are trying to do `series1[1].name` but `series1[1]` is undefined and has no `name` property.

Your script would be stopping at that point, so the line `if (seriesCounter == names.length) {` isn't reached.

I suggest you declare `series1` as an empty array and then within the loop add a new item as needed:

```
...
var series1 = [];
...
$.each(names, function (i, name) {
    $.getJSON('somurl', function (items) {
        // create new object
        series1[i] = { name: name, data: []};
        ...
```

(You don't have the same problem with `series2` because although you've declared it as an array too you only ever access array element 0.)

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
var series1 = [{ name: '', data: []}];
var series2 = [{ name: '', data: []}];
...
series1[i].name = name;
```

series1 is never given an additional object, so on the second iteration, it tries to access the undefined array value at `series[1]`